# Flutter firebase messaging not work on android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i try do example flutter app get notification from firebase. I have done everything suggested in the various guides. but I'm in trouble, in ios the code works perfectly, while on android it doesn't and I can't explain why. It seems that when `_firebaseMessaging.getToken ()` is executed it leads nowhere and waits for a response that never comes. some of you have some tips? I tried all the functions made available by `_firebaseMessaging` but without success.

```
  import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'dart:io' show Platform;
  import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

  class PushMessagingExample extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _PushMessagingExampleState createState() => _PushMessagingExampleState();
  }

  class _PushMessagingExampleState extends State<PushMessagingExample> {
    String _homeScreenText = "Waiting for token...";
    String _messageText = "Waiting for message...";
    final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

    @override
    void initState() {
      debugPrint('test firebase');

      super.initState();
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          setState(() {
            _messageText = "Push Messaging message: $message";
          });
          print("onMessage: $message");
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          setState(() {
            _messageText = "Push Messaging message: $message";
          });
          print("onLaunch: $message");
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          setState(() {
            _messageText = "Push Messaging message: $message";
          });
          print("onResume: $message");
        },
      );



      _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
          const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
      _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
          .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
        print("Settings registered: $settings");
      });

        _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('all');

      debugPrint('token call');
      _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
        debugPrint('test firebase token: $token');
        print(token);
        assert(token != null);
        setState(() {
          _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
        });
        print(_homeScreenText);
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Push Messaging Demo'),
          ),
          body: Material(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text(_homeScreenText),
                ),
                Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(_messageText),
                  ),
                ])
              ],
            ),
          ));
    }
  }

  void main() {
    runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: PushMessagingExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try attaching an `onError` callback to `getToken()`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, there are no error on that call only debug message i find is: /flutter ( 7524): test firebase
I/flutter ( 7524): android push
I/flutter ( 7524): token call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 7524): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging( 7524): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.denisg.googlepushtest. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Comment: I tried with cahtcherror. and in fact the error i get is this:
PlatformException (error, Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.denisg.googlepushtest. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp (Context) first., Null, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.denisg .googlepushtest. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp (Context) first.

I don't understand, with ios I didn't have to initialize anything. There is an initialization method for FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging(); ? or not?

Comment: First, sorry, the callback's indeed called `catchError`. You have to initialize the app by calling `Firebase.initializeApp();`. Note: it's awaitable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! i initialized firebase as you suggested, but it returns this error:
E / flutter (16938): [ERROR: flutter / lib / ui / ui_dart_state.cc (177)] Unhandled Exception: [core / not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "google-services.json" file to the project?

the google-services.json file exist in the android / app folder. Did I forget something in your opinion?

Comment: Well, did you add the json?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is an asynchronous method, first, divide them into Future methods and into methods to create different FirebaseMessaging instances.

Comment: thanks for your reply, why you think that? in ios works, the problem looks like something about google-services.json or inizialize firebase correcly for android.